# Antd V5 Custom Theme for Components

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need my primary color to be a special green color *#1bb470*

After updating the token properties I still have different components like the Layout and Menu with the default color set to *#001529*

Why?

Example: Rule

```
:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-154n70z).ant-layout .ant-layout-sider {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 0;
    background: #001529;
    transition: all 0.2s,background 0s;
}
```

Code Snippet:

```
<ConfigProvider
  theme={{
    token: {
      // Seed Token
      colorPrimary: '#1bb470',
      colorInfo: '#1bb470',
      fontFamily: 'Lato, sans-serif',
    },
    components: {
      Layout: {
        colorBgHeader: '#fff',
      },
      Menu: {
        colorItemBg: '#fff', // colorBgBase -3% lightness
        colorSubItemBg: '#fff', // colorBgBase -3% lightness
      },
    },
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change `Sider` color just add `siderBg` prop inside `Layout` style config and to change `Menu` color add `darkItemBg`:

```
<ConfigProvider
  theme={{
    token: {
      ....
    },
    components: {
      Layout: {
        siderBg: "red" // add this
        ...          
      },
      Menu: {
        darkItemBg: "blue" // add this
        ...
      }
    }
  }}
>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sider-antd-5-10-0-forked-knpwp3) is a working codesandbox example.

You can find a list of all configurable token style settings in section `# Design Token` at end of each component page:

- [`Layout`](https://ant.design/components/layout#design-token) tokens list.
- [`Menu`](https://ant.design/components/menu#design-token) tokens list

Comment: It definitely has an effect on the color. But why do I have to set these colors explicitly, when I already have set the primary color?

Comment: I suppose that these components uses static colors instead of token brand color. Looking into [theme editor](https://ant.design/theme-editor) I could'nt find any `#001529` color generated in any style token and there's no way to see `Sider` component on it and on `Menu` component you can see that `darkItemBg` is not affected by `primaryColor` prop so this should be the reason. Perhaps you should fill an issue on [antd's github](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design).